# Can't start because *.so is missing from your computer

Tags: dll, winsock, winsock2

I'm struggling really hard to make it work so I decided to look for help here.

I've written a program using Winsock2, for Windows, and no matter what I try, the library bundle that I create after compiling the objects seems to not be found (even testing my Makefile script with other program that compiles multiple sources) and there are all commands that I execute:

```
gcc -Isrc -c src/socketutils.c -o obj/socketutils.o
gcc -Isrc -c src/protocolutils.c -o obj/protocolutils.o
ar rcs lib/libacolytus.a obj/socketutils.o obj/protocolutils.o
gcc -c main.c -o obj/main.o -lwsock32 -lws2_32
gcc -shared -fPIC -o lib/libacolytus.so obj/socketutils.o obj/protocolutils.o -lwsock32 -lws2_32
gcc -o main main.c lib/libacolytus.so
```

But although everything runs fine, when I try to execute the `main.exe` the following error appears. What shall I do? (`Windows 8.1` and `MinGW GCC 7.3.0`)

[image: Error when I try to execute the compiled program]

Comment: shouldn't windows be using dynamically linked libraries instead of shared objects?

Comment: Are you sure `-fPIC` is valid for Windows? It looks like you're trying to mix Windows and Linux in the same application, and you can't do that; you need to compile everything for the appropriate target.

Comment: @KenWhite not much, but it does not actually hurt to put it there too.

Comment: You ignored the most important part of my comment, which was not that first sentence.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I think that should be the case too, I will try look for it.

Comment: @KenWhite I did not ignore it, I actually answered it, using `-fPIC` under Windows is not valid but it do not break the entire command.

Comment: That's still not what I said. **Ignore that sentence.** Look at the **other sentence** in that comment. You can't mix Windows and Linux code, and .so (shared object) files are Linux files. WIndows uses a different technology that uses DLLs instead.